# Focus on next row input with square bracket attribute name

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function that will focus on the next textbox while pressing 'enter' key, with square brackets in the name attribute.

I am able to make it focus to the next input inside the same div e.g a[] to b[], b[] to c[], but i couldn't make it focus to the a[] in next div from c[].

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 3px">
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 0px">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="4" name="a[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="b[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="c[]">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 3px">
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 0px">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="4" name="a[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="b[]">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 1px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="5" name="c[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input[name="c[]"]').on('keydown', function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == 13){
        //Enter
        event.preventDefault();

        // function to focus next a[] textbox

        //$('[name="b[]"]').closest('.row').find('[name="b[]"]').focus();

    }
 });
```

Comment: So you want to from the first  `c[]` to the second `a[]`? Also for what purpose? If you setup the tab order (or not usually) you can just hit tab like every other form.

Comment: @Jack user requirement. they will be using the number pad for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the next div with class `.row`  and use `.next()` to move to the next div.

```
$('input[name="c[]"]').on('keydown', function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == 13){
        //Enter
        event.preventDefault();

        // function to focus next a[] textbox

        $(this).closest('.row').next(".row").find('input[name="a[]"]').focus();

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will cycle through once. http://jsfiddle.net/b6fLv71m/

```
var inputs = $('input').on('keydown', function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == 13){
        //Enter
        inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What if there is multiple row ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, did you look at the fiddle?